error linking when using the redis-plus-plus (sw::redis) library
I am trying to use redis++ (C++) under Windows and have some problems link to the installed library.
The redis-plus-plus:x64-windows 1.3.13 and hiredis:x64-windows 1.2.0 have been installed with vcpkg, which can be seen when running .\vcpkg list. Their path is C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include<hiredis> or <sw\redis>.
A code snippet in CMakeLists is as following:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(redis_test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")

find_package(redis++ CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(hiredis CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(redis_sample    
    redis_sample.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(redis_sample
    redis++::redis++ 
    hiredis::hiredis
)

And I am trying to run a simple start code:
#include <sw/redis++/redis++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace sw::redis;

int main()
{
        auto redis = Redis("tcp://127.0.0.1:6379");
        redis.set("key", "val");
}

The code compiles fine but fails at the linking stage. while when I run make -C D:\redis_test/build/, error occuers:
E:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/redis_sample.dir/objects.a(redis_sample.cpp.obj): in function `main':
D:/redis_test/sample/redis_sample.cpp:11:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `sw::redis::Redis::set(sw::redis::StringView const&, sw::redis::StringView const&, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1000ll> > const&, sw::redis::UpdateType)'
E:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/redis_sample.dir/objects.a(redis_sample.cpp.obj): in function `sw::redis::Redis::Redis(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/sw/redis++/redis.h:64:(.text$_ZN2sw5redis5RedisC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN2sw5redis5RedisC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x2e): undefined reference to `sw::redis::Uri::Uri(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
E:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/sw/redis++/redis.h:64:(.text$_ZN2sw5redis5RedisC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN2sw5redis5RedisC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x41): undefined reference to `sw::redis::Redis::Redis(sw::redis::Uri const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [sample/CMakeFiles/redis_sample.dir/build.make:120: sample/redis_sample.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/redis_test/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:98: sample/CMakeFiles/redis_sample.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/redis_test/build'
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory 'D:/redis_test/build'

Im not sure which part is wrong. I would be really grateful if you could offer some help. Thanks a lot.
I have tried to compile the redis++ myself.
But when I run D:\redis-plus-plus-master\build>cmake ...
An error happened:
Could not find HIREDIS_HEADER using the following files: hiredis

So i'm not sure if there's a problem with hiredis.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Images are replaced with code blocks. thanks for your remind. @3CxEZiVlQ

This is the same issue https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/issues/224

I have solved it by installing redis-plus-plus:x64-mingw-dynamic and hiredis:x64-mingw-dynamic instead of x64-windows. It seems that x64-windows version works with msvc and x64-mingw works with mingw together. And after fixed some further bugs, it works at last.

avoid absolute paths in a CMakeLists.txt, it will not work on other machine.

The relevant answer to the duplicate question is:Your linkage contains C++ object files and C++ libraries originating from different C++ compilers
